"Outer" $L^p$ norms of non-measurable functions
I am trying to understand why $L^p$-spaces of functions on a measure space $X$ are defined as composed of classes of measurable functions, while it is obviously possible to generalise the $L^p$ norm to include some non-measurable functions.
Namely, we can define the "outer" $L^p$ norm of an arbitrary function $f$ by
$$
  \Vert f\Vert_p\overset{\text{def}}{=}\inf_{g: (\forall x)(|f(x)|\le g(x))}\Vert g\Vert_p
$$
where the infimum is over all measurable $g$ which pointwise bound $|f|$ from above.
If we allow $\Vert f\Vert_p$ to be infinite, then it is well-defined for all functions $f$, not just measurable ones.
Moreover, we can similarly define such an "outer" $L^p$ norm on (classes of) vector-valued functions on a measure space that take values in a normed vector space:
$$
  \Vert f\Vert_p\overset{\text{def}}{=}\inf_{g: (\forall x)(\Vert f(x)\Vert\le g(x))}\Vert g\Vert_p
$$
where the infimum is over all measurable real-valued $g$ such that $\Vert f(x)\Vert\le g(x)$ for all $x$.
I suspect such "outer" $L^p$ norms of arbitrary functions on a measure space $X$ can be defined from a pre-measure on a semi-ring of subsets of $X$ without having to first define measurable sets and measurable functions.
I am interested in any references to articles or studies that deal with such generalised $L^p$ spaces.
In particular, I would be interested in an "intrinsic" definition of the subspaces of measurable functions.

Update.
I've found that Bourbaki use this kind of (semi-)norms in  Intégration -- Chapitres 1 à 4 (English translation in: Integration I -- Chapters 1-6).
I may post it as an answer after I study it more.

In addition to Bourbaki's Intégration, you can have a look at Stone's Notes on integration, I and II. Stone does something a little similar to Bourbaki.

There's also this paper by Bauer in which you might be interested (the first two paragraphs), as well as two books (the older one, the more recent one) by Bichteler. Though these are all very similar to what Bourbaki does…

At least when $1\leq p<\infty$, it is possible to define the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_p$, the seminormed space $\mathscr L^p$ and the normed space $L^p$ before even introducing any notion of measurability.

Summary of the Bourbaki-style definition of $L^p$ spaces
In Bourbaki's Intégration, in all the texts I mentionned in my comments and many more (Bauer, Bichteler, Bichteler but more recent, Daniell, Dieudonné, Godement, Schwartz, Sondermann, Stone I II III IV) the starting point of integration is a little different than usual: instead of a set $X$, a good class $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$ and a good additive function $m$ on $\Sigma$ as is done in most contemporary textbooks, they all start with a set $X$, a good vector space $\mathscr R$ of scalar functions on $X$ and a good positive linear functional $\mu$ on $\mathscr R$.
The $L^p$ spaces are then defined in a few steps:

from the linear functional $\mu$, construct an "upper integral" $\mu^*$ on the set $\overline{\mathbf R}{}_+^X$.
let $\|\mathbf f\|_p=\mu^*(|\mathbf f|^p)^{1/p}$ for any function $\mathbf f$ defined on $X$ and taking its values in $\overline{\mathbf R}$ or in a Banach space $F$.
notice that the set $\mathscr F_F^p=\{\mathbf f\in F^X~|~\|\mathbf f\|_p<+\infty\}$ is a vector space on which $\|\cdot\|_p$ is a seminorm.
let $\mathscr L_F^p$ be the closure in $\mathscr F_F^p$ (for the topology defined by $\|\cdot\|_p$) of $\mathscr R\otimes F$.
let $L_F^p$ be the Hausdorffization of $\mathscr L_F^p$.

Depending on the properties of $\mu$, there can be several different ways to associate an "upper integral" to $\mu$ (in Bauer's paper, compare the formula (2) given in section 2.1 and formula (4) given in section 2.3).
Comparison with the "usual" $L^p$ spaces
Now back to the "usual" setting of a set $X$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $X$ and a countably additive function $m:\Sigma\to\overline{\mathbf R}_+$.
This "usual" setting can be seen to be a particular case of the "functional" setting by letting $\mathscr R$ be the vector space of all scalar $m$-integrable finitely $\Sigma$-simple functions on $X$ and by letting $\mu$ be the naïve $m$-integral of such functions. So an upper integral $\mu^*$ associated to $m$ can be constructed following formula (2) in Bauer's paper, but since it might seem a little unnatural to do, it's interesting to note that
$$\mu^*(f)=\inf\left\{\sum_{y\in s(X)}m(s^{-1}(y))y~\middle|~s:X\to\overline{\mathbf R}_+\text{ countably }\Sigma\text{-simple and }f\leq s\right\}$$
for every $f:X\to\overline{\mathbf R}_+$. That formula is actually the one L. Schwartz uses as definition of the upper integral in the preliminaries of his book on Radon measures.
Bourbaki $\mathscr L^p$ spaces can then be defined with the upper integral and now you may wonder how these $\mathscr L^p$ compare to the "usual" $\mathscr L^p$ spaces of $ \Sigma$-measurable functions. The "usual" integral of a nonnegative $\Sigma$-measurable function can be checked to coincide with its upper integral, so it all boils down to the question:

Are the functions in the Bourbaki $\mathscr L^p$ spaces necessarily $\Sigma$-measurable?

It turns out the answer is no in general.
However, it can be shown that a function $f$ defined on $X$ and taking its values in a separable Banach space $F$ belongs to the Bourbaki $\mathscr L_F^p$ space if and only if it is measurable with respect to the $m$-completion of $\Sigma$ and satisfies $\|f\|_p<+\infty$. So the Bourbaki-style definition of $\mathscr L^p$ space automatically completes the $\sigma$-algebra, and it does even more than that… In any case, after taking quotients, the "usual" $L_F^p$ space and the Bourbaki $L_F^p$ space can be seen to be isometrically isomorphic.
A somewhat detailed discussion of what notion of measurability is good with the Bourbaki $\mathscr L^p$ spaces can be found in Bichteler's older book, chap. III, § 1, especially Theorem 19.5 which offers several characterisations of measurability. The link between this and Carathéodory measurability is the subject of an exercise in Bourbaki's Intégration (exerc. 13 of chap. IV, § 5).
